# Reading PDFs that have been run through ABBYY OCR software in R

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying to clean up data from old pdf reports using R. The reports can be run through `ABBYY OCR` software and output into text files for each original pdf. The end goal is to create a data frame that contains 7 columns. 
Using `readLines` and `as.data.frame`, I am able to import the text file into data frame that always has a consistent structure, but has a variable number of elements based on the number of text paragraphs in the document.

```
X1

1 Company name

2 Author;date

3 Division

4 Topic (like keywords)

5 … X -1    Body of text

X   Total (this is a number that needs to be captured)
```

What I am having trouble with is taking the variable rows (5 to X-1) and combining them into a single text block.  I know I can split the author and date into two separate columns using `tidyr` (though I would be grateful for any help with distinguishing between American and European formats on the fly) 
The final output should be something like –

```
Company.name    Author          Date        Division    Topic       Body            Total
“Xcorp”         “John Mills”    20 AUG 1987 “FLA”   “   ”Widget 1”  “We saw demand…”    187,921
```

Any ideas on how I can approach this issue?  If I missed this in searching the site, please tell me the terms used, I am newish to R and might not know the right terminology.

Comment: can you post some of the data?

Comment: Without some data, any attempt is futile. In addition, OCR isn't very true (this is why standard formats are there for) and I suspect you may get some variation in your raw files. Can you check how stable the results are?

Comment: Thank you Chris, you are right I should have supplied serval records so it would show the differences in the imported records.  I am lucky that the OCR process has been highly accurate on these forms, perhaps because the format has not changed in years.  I will pull a sample of a few and clean them up of any company information and post them Monday.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: Hi Chris, I found the answer to my problem.  By using the tidyr function unite() I am able to join the range of columns that are imported from the OCR text file and have a clean data set. Sorry to trouble you.
Thanks
Jim